# Windows 8 is missing 21GB worth of space

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, disk-space

I bought and built my computer and installed Windows 8 on it. Everything was fine (never really checked my system's hard drive though).

Whenever I install huge software (i.e  games, etc.) I do that on another partition (same drive). I only install tools (compilers, video converters, media player and other file format reader, etc.) on the system partition.

Some info about my directories (size - on disk size)

```
C:\Windows                    13.9 - 14.1 GB
both Program Files (together) 7.78 - 7.98 GB
C:\Programs                   1.09 - 1.12 GB
C:\Users\Default\AppData      87.6 - 236  KB
```

[image: disk properties]

My whole C: partition is about 55.5 GB and as you can see in the picture all files/directories use together about 28.1 - 28 GB of space (hidden folders such as ProgramData are visible and selected as you can see). However I only have about 7.43 GB of free space.

Is there a particular reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most likely hidden files such as those for system restore, paging files, and hibernation files. Use a program like [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) that's specifically intended to show all used space, not just the sizes of things users ordinarily manage.

Comment: pagefile.sys takes a lot of space

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need hibernation, turn it off: `powercfg -h off`
64GB is not very much for windows. Install some updates and drivers, and the ssd will be full!

Comment: Great, gained 7GB with this trick. 
Yes, 64GB doesn't seem enough (for windows 8). I don't understand why microsoft didn't that take into account when they wrote the system requirements [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements) (20GB). they may certainly have known that Average Joe wouldn't create a "Program Files" partition. And even with my partition it wasn't enough.